# Calculating the annualized average returns

Tags: excel, finance, accounting

How do I calculate the annualized average returns? I have tha data for each month over several years and I now have to calculate the annualized average.

[image: Sample Data for 2 years]

Comment: average returns = (total sum of all returns) / (total number of returns)

Comment: Would you show the first annualize average return rate?

Comment: I don't think this would work: (total sum of all returns) / (total number of returns). As Interest rates are compound and its a geometric average.

Comment: One approach I've seen is to annualize each month separately (using  [((1 + R)^12) - 1] x 100) and then average the annualized rates. Though, IIUC, this isn't universally accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works:

```
=EFFECT((GEOMEAN(1+B1:B36)-1)*12,12)
```

entered as an array formula with `ctrl+shift+enter`

With your values it --> `7.843%`

`GEOMEAN` --> the average monthly return.

The `+1`, `-1` operations are because `GEOMEAN` requires all entries to be positive.

`* 12` --> the annual nominal return

`EFFECT` --> the effective return.